# Troubleshooting ggplot2 stacked bar plot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked identity barplot but `ggplot2` keeps lumping my data together.

Instead of providing the stacked plot with each respective categories for each sector, it's aggregating the `direct`, `indirect.down` and `indirect.up` categories together.

```
test.df = data.frame(scenario=(c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3",
                             "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3",
                             "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3")),
              sector=(c("Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services",
                        "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services",
                        "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Agriculture", "Manufacturing", "Services" )),
              loss=(runif(27,0,1000)), shock=(c("direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down",
                        "direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down",
                        "direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down","direct", "indirect.up", "indirect.down")))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test.df, aes(x=sector, y=loss)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=shock))  + facet_wrap(~ scenario) + coord_flip()
```

I want it to look like this in terms of how the shocks to each sector are stacked:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your sample data, each `sector` has only one kind of `shock` associated to it.

```
table(test.df$sector, test.df$shock)

#              direct indirect.down indirect.up
# Agriculture        9             0           0
# Manufacturing      0             0           9
# Services           0             9           0
```

Adding some data to create some more associations between `sector` and `shock`:

```
df2 <- test.df

df2$shock[df2$shock == "indirect.down"] <- "indirect.up"
df2$shock[df2$shock == "direct"] <- "indirect.down"

test.df <- rbind(test.df, df2)

table(test.df$sector, test.df$shock)

#               direct indirect.down indirect.up
# Agriculture        9             9           0
# Manufacturing      0             0          18
# Services           0             9           9
```

Test your code now:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test.df, aes(x=sector, y=loss)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=shock))  +
 facet_wrap(~ scenario) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sumedh, I have now rectified the problem.